# Why can't I substitute a slice of one type for another in Go?

Tags: go, covariance

I'm trying to understand Go's type conversion rules. Say we have these interfaces:

```
type woofer interface {
  woof()
}

type runner interface {
  run()
}

type woofRunner interface {
  woofer
  runner
}
```

and to satisfy the interfaces we have a `dog` type:

```
type dog struct{}

func (*dog) run()  {}
func (*dog) woof() {}
```

These two functions are using the interfaces:

```
func allWoof(ws []woofer) {}

func oneWoof(w woofer) {}
```

To use these methods I can write the following:

```
dogs := make([]woofRunner, 10)
oneWoof(dogs[0])
allWoof(dogs)
```

The first function `oneWoof()` works as expected; a `*dog` implements all `oneWoof` needs, which is a `woof` function.

However for the second function `allWoof`, Go won't compile the attempted invocation, reporting the following:

> cannot use dogs (type []woofRunner) as type []woofer in argument to allWoof

Using a type conversion is also impossible; writing `[]woofer(dogs)` fails as well:

> cannot convert dogs (type []woofRunner) to type []woofer

Every member of `[]woofRunner` has all the necessary functions to satisfy a `[]woofer`, so why is this conversion prohibited?

(I'm not sure if this is the same case explained in the Go [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) and in various questions on Stack Overflow in which people ask about converting type `T` to `interface{}`. Every pointer in the slice/array is pointing to a type that is directly convertible to another type. Using these pointers should be possible for the same reason that passing `dog[0]` to 'oneWoof` is possible.)

**Note 1**: I know one solution is to loop over and and convert the items one by one. My question here is why that's necessary and whether there is a better solution.

**Note 2**: Regarding the rules of [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability):

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T [when] T is an interface type and x implements T.

Can't we say if the type of the slice/array is assignable to another type, then arrays of those types are also assignable?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability So that assignment simply does not fit the language standard assignability rules.

Comment: why: Because that's how type conversion works. And no, there is no better solution.

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface. Rule of thumb: Check Effective Go, the FAQ, the Tour of Go and the Language Spec. The answer will be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Go's refusal to convert slices along these variance relationships addressed in other answers here, it's useful to think through *why* Go refuses to do so, even when the in-memory representation would be the same between the two types.

In your example, supplying a slice of `woofRunners`s as a parameter of type `[]woofer` is asking for [*covariant* treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Arrays) of the slice's element type. When **reading** from the slice, indeed, since a `woofRunner` *is a* `woofer`, you know that every element present in a `[]woofRunner` will satisfy a reader looking for `[]woofer`.

However, in Go, a slice is a reference type. When passing a slice as an argument to a function, the slice is copied, but the copy used in the invoked function body continues to refer to the same backing array (absent reallocation necessary before `append`ing beyond its capacity). The mutable view of an array—more generally, inserting an item into a collection—requires *contravariant* treatment of the element type. That is, when it comes to demanding a function parameter with the intention of **inserting into** or **overwriting** an element of type `woofRunner`, it's acceptable to supply a `[]woofer`.

The question is whether the function is demanding the slice parameter for

- reading from it (for reading `woofer`s, a `[]woofRunner` is just as good as a `[]woofer`),
- writing to it (for writing `woofRunner`s, a `[]woofer` is just as good as a `[]woofRunner`),
- or both (neither is an acceptable substitute for the other).

Consider what would happen if Go did accept slice parameters in covariant fashion, and someone came along and changed `allWoof` as follows:

```
// Another type satisfying `woofRunner`:
type wolf struct{}
func (*wolf) run()  {}
func (*wolf) woof() {}

func allWoof(ws []woofer) {
  if len(ws) > 0 {
    ws[0] = &wolf{}
  }
}

dogs := []*dog{&dog{}, &dog{}}
allWoof(dogs)  // Doesn't compile, but what if it did?
```

Even if Go was willing to treat a `[]*dog` as a `[]woofer`, we would wind up with a `*wolf` in our array of `*dog` here. Some languages defend against such an accident with run-time type checks on the attempted array insertion or overwrite, but because Go precludes us from even making it this far, it doesn't need these additional checks.

Answer (score 2):

From [Go reference](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)

> Two slice types are identical if they have identical element types.

and

> Two interface types are identical if they have the same set of methods with the same names and identical function types(...).

So `woofRunner` isn't identical to `woofer` and this leads us that `[]woofRunner` isn't identical to `[]woofer`.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert arrays of interfaces in a loop:

```
var woofers []woofer
for _, w := range dogs {
    woofers = append(woofers, w)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but please see my edit in which I clarify the type of the question I'm asking