# Go Compare Two Structs For Greater Than

Tags: go

I am trying to compare two playing card structs to see which playing card is better than the other one. Everything I can find online for comparing structs in Go is to compare for equality, but in this case I want to say that an Ace of Spades is more valuable than a 7 of Clubs.

Given that Go does not provide something like Java's comparator interface out of the box, I wanted to create my own function to do card comparison using loops, but I am getting the error message:

```
# cards/card
card/Card.go:12:19: cannot use Ranks (type [13]string) as type []string in argument to indexOfSlice
card/Card.go:14:26: cannot use Ranks (type [13]string) as type []string in argument to indexOfSlice
card/Card.go:15:20: cannot use Suits (type [4]string) as type []string in argument to indexOfSlice
```

This is my Card package:

```
package Card

var Suits = [4]string {"hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs"}
var Ranks = [13]string {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"}

type Card struct {
        Value string
        Suit string
}

// if the index in the slices is greater for a than for b, then a must be greater value
func CardIsGreater(a Card, b Card) bool {
        if indexOfSlice(a.Value, Ranks) > indexOfSlice(b.Value, Ranks) {
                return true;
        } else if indexOfSlice(a.Value, Ranks) == indexOfSlice(b.Value, Ranks) {
                if indexOfSlice(a.Suit, Suits) > indexOfSlice(b.Suit, Suits) {
                        return true;
                }
        } else {
                return false;
        }
        // lets ignore for a second that invalid ranks or suits will break this comparator
        return false;
}

// finds the index of a suit or value in a slice
func indexOfSlice(element string, slice []string) int {
        for i, _ := range slice {
                if slice[i] == element {
                        return i;
                }
        }
        return -1;
}
```

This is my main package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "cards/card"
)

func main () {
    card := Card.Card{Suit: "hearts", Value: "ace"}
    card2 := Card.Card{Suit: "diamonds", Value: "queen"}
    fmt.Println(card)
    fmt.Println(card2)
    fmt.Println(Card.CardIsGreater(card, card2)
}
```

How, in this case, would I get the indexOfSlice helper function to accept a slice of strings as one of its arguments? If I read a random tutorial from the front page of my google search, it looks like it should work: https://nanxiao.gitbooks.io/golang-101-hacks/content/posts/pass-slice-as-a-function-argument.html

This stack overflow answer explains that Go is basically enforcing type safety as type []string can be satisfied by many things: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44606795/7255394. If that is the case, then how do I get around this issue?

Furthermore, is this even the correct way to approach comparing structs? In the case of Ace of Spaces being compared to Ace of Hearts it would take 4 loops over the Suits And Ranks slices (!!) in order to actually get a comparison.

Comment: Please reduce your code so that you have a [example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Suits` and `Ranks` are not slices. They are arrays. An array is a fixed-sized type, and it is different from a slice. You cannot send an array to a function expecting a slice. So, declare them without size, and they will become slices:

```
var Suits=[]string{...}
var Ranks=[]string{...}
```

Or, if you want to keep them as arrays, you have to pass a slice to the function that expects a slice:

```
indexOfSlice(str,Suits[:])
```

About the question for a better way of doing this: you can use a map:

```
var Suits=map[string]int{"hearts":0, "spades":1, "diamonds":2, "clubs":3}
```

Then:

```
rankSuit=Suits[str]
```

Comment: Thank you. It was a situation in which I was confusing arrays and slices.

Answer (score 0):

I would abstract your types, and add some utility functions to them.

Creating custom types for `Card`, `Suit`, and `Rank`, allows you to attach comparison and validity functions to each of them.

If you're wanting a similar interface to `Comparable` in Java, it's a very small interface that you could create yourself, too. It would be simple enough to implement the necessary `CompareTo` functions for your types to satisfy the interface, although, I think that the solution I've provided encapsulates the types a little better and is easier to test.

I've added the logic to compare the `Suit` of the `Card` in the scenario that the `Rank` of both cards is equal, but I'm not entirely sure of the reasoning behind this since usually playing cards with equal rank are considered as equal cards.

Good luck!

---

**cards/card.go**

```
func New(s Suit, r Rank) (*Card, error) {
    if !s.Valid() {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid suit")
    }

    if !r.Valid() {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid rank")
    }

    return &Card{suit: s, rank: r}, nil
}

type Card struct {
    suit Suit
    rank Rank
}

func (c *Card) Cmp(c2 *Card) int {
    rankCmp := c.rank.Cmp(c2.rank)
    if rankCmp != 0 {
        return rankCmp
    }

    if c.suit < c2.suit {
        return -1
    }

    if c.suit > c2.suit {
        return 1
    }

    return 0
}
```

---

**cards/rank.go**

```
type Rank string

var ranks = []Rank{"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"}

func (r Rank) Cmp(r2 Rank) int {
    for _, rank := range ranks {
        if rank == r {
            return -1
        }

        if rank == r2 {
            return 1
        }
    }

    return 0
}

func (r Rank) Valid() bool {
    for _, rank := range ranks {
        if r == rank {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

---

**cards/suit.go**

```
type Suit int

const (
    unknown  Suit = 1
    Hearts   Suit = 2
    Spades   Suit = 3
    Diamonds Suit = 4
    Clubs    Suit = 5
    sentinel Suit = 6
)

func (s Suit) Valid() bool {
    return s > unknown && s < sentinel
}
```

---

**main.go**

```
func main() {
    c1, err := cards.New(Hearts, "2")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    c2, err := New(cards.Diamonds, "A")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    c3, err := New(cards.Spades, "A")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("c1 - c2: %d\n", c1.Cmp(c2))
    fmt.Printf("c2 - c3: %d\n", c2.Cmp(c3))
    fmt.Printf("c1 - c3: %d\n", c1.Cmp(c3))
}
```

---

[(Go Playground)](https://play.golang.com/p/DeiJeLGh1Y1)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169736/7255394 a map was suggested. It is much quicker to compare the values of a map than to implement these interfaces.

I am curious though, why did you create a Suit called sentinel?

Comment: In Go, when I create enums like i have here, I always create a sentinel value rhat remains the last value in the list in order to check validation. See the Valid function. As long as sentinel is always last, I can easily check if an enum is valid. :)